# system call "open" cannot create file with O_CREAT flag

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I've got to complete an exercise using linux's system calls:

1. open the file "testinput.txt" (already present in the working directory, not empty)
2. open the file "testoutput.txt" (not present in the working directory)
3. copy the content of testinput in testoutput
4. close both files

I found that I can open the file with system call `open` can both open the input file (flag `O_RDONLY`) and the output file (flag `O_CREAT | O_WRONLY`).

The input file works correctly. The output file doesn't.

Errno says code 2 = "No such file or direcory" (obviously, I asked to create the file). What am I doing wrong?

P.S.: To highlight I'm using syscalls, I'm not calling function `open(...)` but `syscall(SYS_OPEN, ...)`

```
outFileDesc = syscall(SYS_OPEN, "testoutput.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 438);
if(outFileDesc == -1) {
    int code = errno;

    // gdb used here -> print code -> 2

    char str[] = "Unable to open \"testoutput.txt\"\n";
    syscall(SYS_WRITE, FILE_DESC_STDOUT, str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(char));
    syscall(SYS_CLOSE, inFileDesc);
    syscall(SYS_EXIT, 1);
    return 1;   
}
```

Whole code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* file flags fcntl.h */
#define O_RDONLY    0x0000      /* open for reading only */
#define O_WRONLY    0x0001      /* open for writing only */
#define O_CREAT     0x0200      /* create if nonexistant */
#define O_TRUNC     0x0400      /* truncate to zero length */

#define FILE_DESC_STDOUT 1

#define SYS_EXIT 1
#define SYS_READ 3
#define SYS_WRITE 4
#define SYS_OPEN 5
#define SYS_CLOSE 6

#define IN_MESSAGE_LEN 9
#define OUT_MESSAGE_LEN 9

char inBuffer[IN_MESSAGE_LEN];
char outBuffer[OUT_MESSAGE_LEN];

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int inFileDesc, outFileDesc;

    // Apertura fine di input
    inFileDesc = syscall(SYS_OPEN, "testinput.txt", O_RDONLY, 438);
    if(inFileDesc == -1) {
        char str[] = "Unable to open \"testinput.txt\"\n";
        syscall(SYS_WRITE, FILE_DESC_STDOUT, str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(char));
        syscall(SYS_EXIT, 1);
        return 1;   
    }

    // Apertura fine di output
    outFileDesc = syscall(SYS_OPEN, "testoutput.txt", O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 438);
    if(outFileDesc == -1) {
        int code = errno;

        char str[] = "Unable to open \"testoutput.txt\"\n";
        syscall(SYS_WRITE, FILE_DESC_STDOUT, str, sizeof(str)/sizeof(char));
        syscall(SYS_CLOSE, inFileDesc);
        syscall(SYS_EXIT, 1);
        return 1;   
    }

    // Travaso contenuto file di input in file di output
    int read, i;
    while((read = syscall(SYS_READ, inFileDesc, inBuffer, IN_MESSAGE_LEN)) != 0) {

        for(i = 0; i < IN_MESSAGE_LEN; i++) {
            outBuffer[i] = inBuffer[i];
        }

        syscall(SYS_WRITE, outFileDesc, outBuffer, OUT_MESSAGE_LEN);
    }

    syscall(SYS_CLOSE, inFileDesc);
    syscall(SYS_CLOSE, outFileDesc);

    syscall(SYS_EXIT, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the execution]

Comment: `438` is a really weird way to write `0666`.

Comment: Can you successfully create (and write to) the output file if you use `open()` instead of going through `syscall()`?

Comment: Why not `#include <fcntl.h>`?

Comment: @melpomene this code will be manually translated to assembly by my teammate, I was not sure if he knew how to write 666 in octal. I was so lazy that instead of writing a comment and hoping he check how it has to be made, I solved writing the dec constant

Comment: @jxh in assembly (gas) we have no idea how to include c headers, so we will probably write the constant. 
Because I want this C code similar to the assembly we will write, I decided to write directly the constants (for the same reason I used syscall() instead of open(), write() and so on).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran your code under [`strace`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and got:

```
...
open("testinput.txt", O_RDONLY)         = 3
open("testoutput.txt", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
//                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

I.e. your definition of the `O_*` flags is wrong.

As it turns out, there's more than one thing wrong: `0x0200` is actually `O_TRUNC` (not `O_CREAT`), and `0x0400` is actually `O_APPEND` (not `O_TRUNC`).

Changing it to

```
#define O_CREAT 0x0040
#define O_TRUNC 0x0200
```

makes it work.