# Wrong O_CREAT definition

Tags: c, linux

I included following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

and my `open("file", O_CREAT || O_RDWR)` sets errno to **ENOENT**. In gdb I see this:

```
Breakpoint 1, xxx() at xxx.c:130
130 fd = open("file", O_CREAT || O_RDWR);
(gdb) s
__libc_open64 (file=0x55555555604e "file", oflag=1) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c:37
37  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb)
```

I saw this answer:
[system call "open" cannot create file with O_CREAT flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38026725/system-call-open-cannot-create-file-with-o-creat-flag) and it seems probable, however my **O_CREAT** is defined as 0x40 and **O_RDWR** as 0x2 which are google most popular choices (I tried setting **O_CREAT** to 0x100, but it did not help).

Is there a way to find out what value is my open() expecting?

Comment: you can do only bit wise operators on flags (in this case to open system call). you are mistaken and used by mistake the logical or || and not the bitwise or |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the inclusive bit or operator, `|`, with your flags.  The logical or operator, `||`, will, when treated as a numerical value, always be equal to either 1 or 0.